# Purpose of the Tag field on Add View page?

Tags: views, blocks, theming

Under the Tag field on the Add View Page is such note:

> Enter an optional tag for this view;
>   it is used only to help sort views on
>   the administrative page.

But I also noticed that when I fill this field out another template becomes available with tagname in it's name. I should say that that might be quite handy in my case, when I kinda need to narrow the hit to specific views only. Can I perhaps use this feature to granulate templates for the views?

Any other usage case for the Tag field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, the tag field is handy for sites that have a lot of views.Different views have different purposes; for instance admin/editor tasks, front end pages and blocks, or as source for node reference fields. If you tag your views consistently, it's easier to find a view when you need to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Except for obvious sorting and organization purposes, Tag field is also used in views Theme Information as suggestion template. For example Views tagged with "MYTAG" will use this template - views-view-unformatted--MYTAG.tpl.php.
This is very usefull when u have multiple different but similar views that u want would use same template file.

See Comments at:
http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2014/04/sharing-templates-between-multiple-drupal-views